# Cardinality of the set $\{(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_p)\in \mathcal{P}(E)^p \mid X_1\subset\cdots\subset X_p \}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, binomial-coefficients, equivariant-maps

> If $|E|=n$ is a set, what is the cardinality of the set
>   $$\{(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_p)\in \mathcal{P}(E)^p \mid X_1\subset\cdots\subset X_p   \}$$

**My thoughts**

The giving of p-tuplets $X_0=\emptyset\subset X_1\subset  X_2\subset\ldots \subset X_p\subset X$ $(p\leq n )$ is to give back 
$$f:X\to \{0,1,\ldots,p\}\quad  \left(f(x)=\max\{i\mid x \not\in X_i\}\right) \mbox{with $f$ is bijective map}$$.

Then $$|\{(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n)\in \mathcal{P}(E)^p \mid X_1\subset\cdots\subset X_p   \}|=|\{0,1,\ldots,p\}^E|=|\{0,1,\ldots,p\}|^{|E|}=(p+1)^n$$

- Is my proof correct also we could prove it with that way  $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom {n} {k} (p)^k=(p+1)^n$ am i right

**Second proof:**
If $|X_p|=k$ So there is  $C_n^k \times p^k$ ways to achieve p-tuples 
but |Y|=k can take all integer values $0$ and $n$. therefore the total number of ways to achieve p-tuples inclusion is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom {n} {k} (p)^k=(p+1)^n$$

Comment: Does $\subset$ mean "subset" or "proper subset"?

Comment: I think you mean surjective, not bijective. After all, $|X|$ could be much bigger than $p.$

Comment: @bof $\subset$ mean "subset"  and $p\leq n$

Comment: Is the set really supposed to look this way or should it be $\{(X_1, \ldots, X_p) \subset \mathcal{P}(E)^p \mid \ldots \}$?

Comment: @Dominik Thanks i fixed the typo

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to calculate the cardinality of the set $M = \{(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_p)\in \mathcal{P}(E)^p \mid X_1\subset\ldots\subset X_p\}$, your solution is correct. However, your solution is poorly worded. A better version could look like this:

Let $X_0 = \emptyset$ be the empty set and let for every $p$-tuple $X = (X_1, \ldots, X_p)$ the function $f_X: E \to \{0, \ldots, p\}$ be defined via $x \mapsto \max \{i \mid x \notin X_i\}$. This construction induces a bijection between $M$ and $\{0, \ldots, p\}^E$ via $M \ni X \mapsto f_X$ and therefore yields $|M| = |\{0, \ldots, p\}^E| = (p + 1)^n$.

**Edit:** To formalize your second proof: For each $k \in \{0, \ldots, n\}$ we have $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to choose $X_p$ so that $|X_p| = k$. Similar to the first proof we can define a function via $f(x) = \min\{i \mid x \in X_i\}$ which yields $p^k$ possible ways to choose the sets $X_1, \ldots, X_p$. The result then follows from summing over all these possibilities and applying the binomial theorem.

Comment: see my update for teh second proof

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with your second proof.

Comment: the second method ( way ) to prove it

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand what you're doing in that proof. It was already difficult to guess what you're doing in the first proof, but I have no idea what you do in the second one.

Comment: see my update please

Comment: The idea behind your second proof is correct [if you start the sum with $k = 0$], but it's still written down very rudimentary.

Comment: could you add better version

Comment: I've added a more understandable version of your second proof to my answer.

Comment: could you suggest  me some good textbook with exercise and solution of Enumerative combinatorics

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a reference, as I've never read any book about combinatorics.

Comment: okay no problem, thank you

Comment: how can i show that is  construction induces a bijection

Comment: By proving that $X \mapsto f_X$ is an actual bijection.

Comment: could you help me with that and could you check that question please : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605683/cardinality-of-the-set-a-b-in-mathcalpe2-mid-a-cup-b-e