# Cardinality of the set $\{(A,B)\in \mathcal{P}(E)^{2} \mid A\cup B=E \}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, equivariant-maps

> let $E$ be a finite set with $|E|=n$ elements.
>
> - what is the cardinality of set $\mathcal{E}=\{(A,B)\in \mathcal{P}(E)^{2} \mid A\cup B=E \}$

My proof:

note that $A\cup B=E \iff A^{c}\subset B $
$$|\mathcal{E}|= | \{ (A,B)\in\mathcal{P}(E)^{2} \ / \ A^{c} \subset B \} |$$

Let for every $(A^{c},B)$ the function $f: E \to \{0,1,2\}$ be defined via : 
  $$f(x)= 
    \begin{cases}
       0 &  \mbox{ if } \quad x\in A^{c} \\
& \\
       1 & \mbox{ if } \quad x\in  B\backslash A^{c} \\
& \\
       2 & \mbox{ if } \quad x\in  E\backslash B
   \end{cases}
 $$

This construction induces a bijection between $\mathcal{E}$ and $\{0,1,2\}^E$ via :
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \mathcal{T} & : & \mathcal{E} & \to & \{0,1,2\}^E \\
 & & (A^{c},B) & \mapsto & f \\
\end{array}$$

and therefore yields $|\mathcal{E}| = |\{0,1,2\}^E| = (2 + 1)^n=3^n$

- Is my proof correct. I'm interested in more ways of prove it

Comment: Your proof contains no mistakes, but I think you need to explain in more detail why your function is a bijection.

Comment: we can't say that is by construction it's bijecticion ?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof looks basically correct, but it has some weaknesses.

You use the "complement" notation $A^c$ but never state your universal set. (You seem to imply that it is $E$.) For that and other reasons you should avoid the complement and stick to set difference.

Your notation for the value $f(x)=1$ is unnecessarily complicated. Why not just use $A\cap B$? That would go well with $E\setminus B$ for $0$ and $E\setminus A$ for $2$.

I agree with @BenMillwood's comment that you should show more detail that your construction makes a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

Pick $A$ first. If $A$ has $k$ elements (there are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to choose these), then we *must* pick all $n-k$ elements in $B$, so there are $2^k$ many choices of complementary sets (namely all subsets of $A$ can be added to the compulsory elements of $B$). So we have $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} 2^k$ many choices, which amounts to $3^n$ by Newton's binomial formula (expand $(1+x)^n$ with $x=2$).